# JavaScript is not working properly for show / hide function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the bootstrap modal form, I want to show some fields based on the option selected in the select field, its working as expected for the first row, but it's not from the 2nd rows.

Client List Table

```
S.No    Client_Name          Update_Status
1        Client1               Update       
2        Client2               Update       
3        Client3               Update       
4        Client4               Update
```

By clicking the update button, it will open a bootstrap modal

Update button code

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leadModal<?php echo $row1['leads_id'] ?>">Update</a>
```

Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="leadModal<?php echo $row1['leads_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Comments</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form action="" method="POST">
        <select name="status" id="select" required>
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Choose Status</option>
          <option value="NA">No Answer</option>
          <option value="Demo">Appointment</option>
          <option value="IP">In Progress</option>
          <option value="NI">Not Interested</option>
          <option value="complete">Lead Complete</option>
        </select>
        <div class="select3" id="select3">
          <select class="mt-2" name="trainer" required>
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Select the Trainer</option>
          <option value="Trainer 1">Trainer 1</option>
          <option value="Trainer 2">Trainer 2</option>                     
          </select>
         </div>
         <div class="select2" id="select2">
          <select class="mt-2" name="trainer" required>
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Select the Package</option>
          <option value="Trainer 1">Package 1</option>
          <option value="Trainer 2">Package 2</option>                     
          </select>
         </div>
       </form>
                        
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Java Script Code

```
<script>
    $("#status").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'complete'){
      $("#select2").show();
      $("#select3").hide();
    }else if($(this).val() == 'Demo'){
      $("#select3").show();
      $("#select2").hide();
    }else{
      $("#select2").hide();
      $("#select3").hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

It's working fine, for the first update button (Client 1 row) but the javascript function is not working for the rest of the rows.

Comment: What is the reason for tagging this question with `php` tag?

Comment: @user2468312  You are giving id to modal of $row1[leads_id] only so which means the all update button from row 2 will be on different id and you have only one modal.

Comment: _JavaScript is not working properly_ **Its the end of the world as we know it** PANIC